# What's the heaviest metal that uses a capo?

Tags: metal, guitar

Some examples of musicians that use a capo on their guitar are Lisa Loeb (as seen in recent Geico commercials), and the lead singer of Death Cab for Cutie.

As a musician who plays hard rock, I am aware of the unwritten rule that guitarists should not use a capo to play hard rock/metal.

But are there any metal artists who use a capo?  Maybe some Scandinavian black metal bands?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any (metal) bands doing this, but this guitar cover of Devourment's Shroud of Encryption uses a capo, and arguably belongs to the heavier side of metal:

Comment: I am curious about this.

This guitar isn't tuned to standard E, is it?  I imagine is dropped, and the capo is used here mainly as an alternative to changing the tuning.  My notion of using a capo would be on a standard E tuned guitar used to access higher registers.

Comment: You're right, I'd imagine the E string is dropped to somewhere between C and A. I thought you were interested in the change in timbre of using a capo, but of course in this case it's not a good example

Comment: Or, even better, a capo being used to alter a subset of all the strings, like the 3-low strings, or 4-high strings, etc.